Sitecore Link Inserted at Top of Page Instead of Desired Location
When using the content editor, a user encounters an issue where, upon opening the rich text editor and adding a Sitecore link, the link is placed at the top of the editor instead of at the intended location. This problem occurs only in Edge and Chrome; it works correctly in Firefox.
Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, what was the cause? I'm using the same browser versions and trying to figure out why it's working for everyone else except this particular user on those browsers.
We are on version 10.3 - Managed Cloud.

Are there any errors in the console?

There is not any errors in the console.  :(
